# ASP.NET Button to redirect to another page

Tags: asp.net, button, webforms, visual-studio-2013

How do I code the button such that when I click the button and it brings me to another web form? Let's say the button name is Confirm and the wed form is confirm.aspx ?

```
    protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (guessing that there should be an input here)
    }
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can either do a `Response.Redirect("YourPage.aspx");` or a `Server.Transfer("YourPage.aspx");` on your button click event.
So it's gonna be like the following:

```
protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("YourPage.aspx");
    //or
    Server.Transfer("YourPage.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use `PostBackUrl="~/Confirm.aspx"`

For example:

In your .aspx file

`<asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" Text="Confirm"
PostBackUrl="~/Confirm.aspx" />`

or in your .cs file

`btnConfirm.PostBackUrl="~/Confirm.aspx"`

Comment: What's the advantage of using btn.PostBackUrl versus Response.Redirect?

Comment: check this https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/69851/postbackurl-vs-response-redirect basically PostBackUrl is meant to be used with in same server because it will save viewState.  Response.Redirect can take you to a brand new server/website where brand new session will start

Answer (score 9):

u can use this:

```
protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Response.Redirect("Confirm.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type ="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("viewname","Controllername")'"> Button name</button>
```

for e.g ,

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("register","Home")'">Register</button>
```