# How to redirect to another page after submit with asp.net c# DNN?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I've encountered a problem after I fire the submit button, the page redirect to itself. How do I redirect it to another page after submit?

My submit button also have C# code behind it where it uploads the files to the server, creates a folder and sends out an email.

I assume that server side form control (runat=server) is designed to post-back to self...

Comment: If you want the form to submit to another URL, you'll need to get that URL into the form's action. Otherwise you can response.redirect or similar in the eventhandler in your code

Answer (score 2):

Probably a `Response.Redirect("PageName.aspx")` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I've tried the response.redirect option, it doesn't work. it still redirects back to itself. When I view source, it's action= is targeting back to self, when compile.

Comment: Could we see the onclick event handler for the submit? Including Response.Redirect

Comment: You shouldn't care about form action. We are talking about ASP.NET Web Forms, not?

Comment: I'm running it on DNN CMS, just to let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Response.Redirect("http://...../Default.aspx", false);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

in order to void this

https://www.jasoft.org/Blog/post/solucionar-el-error-thread-was-being-aborted-en-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PostBackUrl="~/Confirm.aspx"`

For example:

In your .aspx file

`<asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" Text="Confirm"
PostBackUrl="~/Confirm.aspx" />`

or in your .cs file

`btnConfirm.PostBackUrl="~/Confirm.aspx"`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23976700/2067560