# Button Click To Send To New Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have tried both `Response.Redirect` and `Server.Transfer` to take me to a new page on button click, but every time my page just refreshes and I am never redirected to the new page.  I have verified the page exists in my project and even copied/pasted the name of the page into my syntax to make sure no weird spaces or anything, but I NEVER get redirected

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        filldropdowns();
    }
}

protected void btn1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("page2.aspx");
    Server.Transfer("page2.aspx"); 
}

    <div id="btn11" algn="center">
        <asp:Button ID="ClickBtn1" runat="server" Text="Push Me" OnClick="btn1_OnClick" OnClientClick="return ValidateData();" />
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateData() {
        var name;
        name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
        if (name == '' || name.trim() == '') {
            alert("Please enter a valid name");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT**

using the `~/` will allow a redirect but it throws the below error.  The page does exist!

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /page2.aspx

**EDIT 2**
This is the markup for my page2 if that matters

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="page2.aspx.cs" Inherits="page2" %>
```

And if I use `localhost` in my redirect it loads no problem, but I am ready to push this out into the interweavings of the web and can not use `localhost` anymore.  What should I change this to?

```
http://localhost:1444/TestProject/page2.aspx
```

**EDIT 3**
If it helps (or matters) the full location to the .aspx page that I want to redirect to is this:

```
C:\Users\Habib\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Test\TestProject\Page2.aspx
```

Comment: You wrote btnl_OnClick with a letter "l" instead of number "1"

Comment: You can try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/23976700/4660897. Also make sure your aspx page is connected to your code behind page.

Comment: Are page1 and page2 in TestProject folder ?

Comment: @Partha - Yes both pages are

Comment: Try `Response.Redirect("~/TestProject/page2.aspx");`

Comment: @RojalinSahoo - I tried Response.Redirect and it just reloads the page that I am on?  Stepping through the code with F11 it hits the Response.Redirect Line but never takes me to the redirect page.

Comment: Could you show the folder structure from which page  to which page you are redirecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have shown syntax that is known to work whether it be means of `Response.Redirect()` or `Server.Transfer()` those methods are tried and true to be successful.  If when you step through your code it hits your break point for the re-direct, then show us what you have in your `Page_Load()` for `page2.aspx`.

And we can help further diagnose and/or troubleshoot from that.