# Dont know how to make my button link to another html page :(

Tags: html, asp.net

Hello i have asp:button and i want to make him link to another page in my website and i dont really know how to do it because i am using asp:button...
Can anyone help me with that problem?
Please :)
My HTML Button code:

```html
<asp:button ID="RegisterButton" runat="server" Text="הירשם" class="RegisterStyle" onclientclick="var isValid = checkform(); return isValid;" onclick="RegisterButton_Click1" />
```

How can i make this button to linked to another page in my html... :)

Comment: You can either do a Response.Redirect("YourPage.aspx"); or a Server.Transfer("YourPage.aspx") on button click event

Comment: Its not working... please send me how to write it..

Comment: you can follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976683/asp-net-button-to-redirect-to-another-page

Comment: the page that this button is inside has form? you want only to redirect or has a form on the page ?

Comment: @Roie If you just want to redirect to another page than you can set PostbackURL property ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl?view=netframework-4.7.2)) of button  `<asp:button id="Button2" text="Post value to another page" postbackurl="Button.PostBackUrlPage2cs.aspx" runat="Server"></asp:button>` like this or if you want to perform some action on page data than you can use `Response.Redirect("PageName.aspx")` or `Server.Transfer("PageName.aspx")` as @vishu  minhas said

Comment: Its not working bro... I just did like that             <asp:button ID="RegisterButton" runat="server" Text="הירשם" PostBackUrl = "http://localhost:61474/MyWebsite/Home.aspx#" class="RegisterStyle" onclientclick="var isValid = checkform(); return isValid;" onclick="RegisterButton_Click1" />

Comment: iTS NOT LINKING TO MY HOME PAGE :(

Comment: Don't add localhost  to property value just add page name like this `PostBackUrl = "MyWebsite/Home.aspx" ` if your home page is in MyWebsite folder or if your page is in root folder just add page name `PostBackUrl = "Home.aspx" `